# How to find the key of the largest value hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following hash  `{"CA"=>2, "MI"=>1, "NY"=>1}`

How can I return the maximum key value pair using ruby? I would like it to return "CA"

Comment: What if there are multiple keys with the same largest value?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

This will return max hash key-value pair depending on the value of hash elements:

```
def largest_hash_key(hash)
  hash.max_by{|k,v| v}
end
```

Comment: worth noting you get back a 2 element array with [key, value]

Comment: hash.max_by{ |k,v| v }[0] gives the key.

Comment: Also worth noting a tie will go to first in order of position.

Comment: You can also do hash.max_by(&:last) for the pair and hash.max_by(&:last).first for the key.

Comment: Be warned that this does not work if the hash is empty.

Answer (score 48):

I found this way , return the key of the first max value

```
hash.key(hash.values.max)
```

Comment: While `hash[key]` is very efficient, `hash.key(value)` has to search the whole hash. This answer searches the hash twice: first to find the maximum value, then to find the key which matches that value.

Answer (score 14):

Another way could be as follows:

```
hash.each { |k, v| puts k if v == hash.values.max }
```

This runs through each key-value pair and returns (or in this case puts's) the key(s) where the value is equal to the max of all values. This should return more than one key if there's a tie.

Comment: This is a really remarkably inefficient solution, and it's more typing that the other much more efficient solutions.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to retrieve more than one key value pair based on order(second largest, smallest etc.), a more efficient way will be to sort the hash once and then get the desired results.

```
def descend_sort(hash)
   hash = hash.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse
end
```

Key of largest value

```
puts *hash[0][0]
```

Get max and min

```
puts *hash[0], *hash[hash.length-1]
```

2nd largest key value pair

```
Hash[*hash[1]]
```

To convert the hash array back into a hash

```
hash.to_h
```

Answer (score 4):

I did this today on a similar problem and ended up with this:

```
hash = { "CA"=>2, "MI"=>1, "NY"=>1 }

hash.invert.max&.last
=> "CA"
```

For Ruby less than 2.3 you can replace `&.last` with `.try(:last)`
Either one is just a safeguard for if your source hash is empty: `{}`

Answer (score 1):

The answers provided assume there would ever be a single largest value. However, it can have duplicates. To return keys of the largest value, including any duplicates, you can use either of the following methods:

1. `Enumerable#select`;
2. `Hash#each`

```
# 1: using `Enumerable#select`

def max_value_keys(hash)
  max_value = hash.values.max
  max_values = hash.select { | key, value | value == max_value }
  max_values.keys
end

print max_value_keys({ a: 20, b: 50, c: 30 }) #=> [:b]
print max_value_keys({ a: 20, b: 50, c: 50 }) #=> [:b, :c]
```

```
# 2: using `Hash#each`

def max_value_keys(hash)
  max_value = nil
  keys = []

  hash.each do | key, value |
    if max_value.nil? || value > max_value
      max_value = value
      keys = [key]
    elsif value == max_value
      keys << key
    end
  end

  keys
end

print max_value_keys({ a: 20, b: 50, c: 30 }) #=> [:b]
print max_value_keys({ a: 20, b: 50, c: 50 }) #=> [:b, :c]
```

I wrote a [blog post](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-get-hash-map-keys-of-the-maximum-value-in-ruby-including-duplicates) about this, which may be useful for those interested in learning more.

Answer (score -3):

This will return the last key of the hash sorted by size; however, there might be two keys with the same value.

```
def largest_hash_key(hash)
  key = hash.sort{|a,b| a[1] <=> b[1]}.last
  puts key
end

hash = { "n" => 100, "m" => 100, "y" => 300, "d" => 200, "a" => 0 }
largest_hash_key(hash)
```

Comment: selected answer? may_by is much better than a low-level sort. It's more compact and uses less memory than a sort+last.