# Ruby - find the key(s) of the largest value(s) of a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, max

I have a hash and I want to return the key(s) (or key/value pair(s)) of the max value(s) of the hash. So, if there is only one true max, it will return that one key; however, if there are multiple key/value pairs with the same value, it will return all of these keys. How can I accomplish this in Ruby?

```
my_hash.max_by {|k,v| v} #only returns one key/value pair
```

Comment: i guess its the same question answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040494/how-to-find-the-key-of-the-largest-value-hash

Comment: What kind of values are you storing in your hash?  Are you only dealing with integers?

Comment: @yasirhashmi yes, same except I don't want to return only one, I want to return multiple k/v pairs if they have the same value.

Comment: @AmirRubin the key is a string, value is a floating decimal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want all pairs, I would do something like

```
max = my_hash.values.max
Hash[my_hash.select { |k, v| v == max}]
```

Comment: Why === ? I think that might not do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

A single liner:

```
my_hash.reduce({}){|h,(k,v)| (h[v] ||= []) << k;h}.max

irb
> z = {:tree => 3, :two => 2, 'three' => 3}

>  z.reduce({}){|h,(k,v)| (h[v] ||= []) << k;h}.max
[3, [:tree, "three"]]
```