# How to find the max value in an array of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Given this array of hashes here:

```
arr = [{:question_type=>"Fire", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Water", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Metal", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Earth", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Wood", :total=>100.0}]
```

I would like to pick the hash with the highest value for the total key.
So the code bellow seems to do the work

```
max = arr.max_by{|x| x[:total]}
puts max[:question_type]
#=> Wood
```

However if I have 2 hashes with the same value it will return the first one only

```
arr2 = [{:question_type=>"Fire", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Water", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Metal", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Earth", :total=>50.0}, {:question_type=>"Wood", :total=>50.0}]

max = arr2.max_by{|x| x[:total]} #it should be arr2
puts max[:question_type]
#=> Earth
```

What would be the best way to get it to return `Earth` and `Wood` in case both are the highest values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby - find the key(s) of the largest value(s) of a hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005393/ruby-find-the-keys-of-the-largest-values-of-a-hash)

Comment: Use `inject` to build an array of max values.

Comment: @seancdavis if you think a question is duplicate, flag it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with `group_by` and `max`:

```
arr.group_by { |x| x[:total] }.max.last
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in tow steps this way:

```
max = arr.max_by{|x| x[:total]}
max = arr.select{ |x| x[:total] == max[:total }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always just take that max value and `select`.

```
arr = [{:question_type=>"Fire", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Water", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Metal", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Earth", :total=>50.0}, {:question_type=>"Wood", :total=>50.0}]

max = arr.max_by{|x| x[:total]}
max_values = arr.select{|hash| hash[:total] == max[:total]}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to some solid answers already posted here is to roll your own method to retrieve the max values, including multiples if there are ties:

```
def get_max(arr)
  result = []
  current_max = 0.0
  arr.each do |hash|
    if hash[:total] > current_max
      result = [hash[:question_type]]
      current_max = hash[:total]
    elsif hash[:total] == current_max
      result.push(hash[:question_type])
    end
  end
  result
end


arr = [{:question_type=>"Fire", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Water", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Metal", :total=>0.0}, {:question_type=>"Earth", :total=>50.0}, {:question_type=>"Wood", :total=>50.0}]
puts get_max(arr)
# => ["Earth", "Wood"]
```

It may not be as succinct as using something like `#max_by` and `#select`, but the benefit of the above approach is you only iterate through the array once.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You could refactor this code with `each_with_object` or maybe use `reduce` instead.